# Добавить картинку и еще кое что в Vuforia

Tags: java, android, unity3d, vuforia

Всем привет. Я хочу сделать такую прогу: Чтобы при наведении на объект или qr метку, показывала интерфейс с данными об объекте. Делаю на unity c помощью vuforia.

И тут я застрял, как сделать так чтобы худ изначально была скрытой, а показывала только при распозновании объекта. И кнопка закрыть чтобы убрать худ.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Придется писать скрипт который будет следить за объектами под курсором. Причем если вы хотите чтобы объект сцены и UI придется писать разную реализацию. В первом случае вы проверяете через физику и коллайдеры на наличие скрипта со ссылкой на информацию которую требуется отображать, во втором проверяете наличие UI элемента с включенным RayCast Target.

Примерно вот так:

```
TipState GetTargetUI()
{
    if (!LastObjectUI.gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
    {
        LastObjectUI = null;
        return TipState.None;
    }
    return GetTarget(LastObjectUI);
}

TipState GetTargetCamera(Camera cam)
{
    // create the ray on the mouse position from camera
    Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    RaycastHit hit;

    if (!Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        return TipState.None;

    GameObject currentObject = hit.collider.gameObject;
    return GetTarget(currentObject);
}    

TipState GetTarget(GameObject fromObject)
{
    if (fromObject == null) return TipState.None;
    if (fromObject == LastObject) return TipState.Old;

    GameObject currentObject = fromObject;
    do
    {

        toolTip = currentObject.GetComponent<ToolTip>();

        if (toolTip != null)
        {
            LastObject = fromObject;
            TipObject = fromObject;
            Show();
            return TipState.New;
        }

        if (currentObject.transform.parent != null) 
            currentObject = currentObject.transform.parent.gameObject;
        else 
            currentObject = null;
    } while (currentObject != null);
    return TipState.None;
}

public void OnEnter(BaseEventData data)
{
    PointerEventData pData = data as PointerEventData;
    if (pData != null && pData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject)
    {
        LastObjectUI = pData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject;
    }
}

public void OnExit(BaseEventData data)
{
    PointerEventData pData = data as PointerEventData;
    if (pData != null && pData.pointerEnter)
    {
        LastObjectUI = null;
        Hide();
    }
}
```

Это выжимка из большого скрипта, который ищет под указателем  объект. Приходится проверять какой объект был до этого под указателем, есть небольшая машина состояний чтобы отрабатывать логику показа подсказки и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: я оказывается вообще нуб. не врубился

Comment: это я тормоз, не разглядел что окошко должно показываться по событию распознавания объектов. Окно собираем в UI и пишем контролллер который слушает событие. Как событие настало контроллер включает окошко. Для окошка лучше собрать все элементы в один пустой контейнер и просто управляем его видимостью через `GameObject.SetActive(bool isActive);`

Comment: да к стати, как можно все сгруппировать ? ото на каждый элемент прописывать не охото)

Comment: так я же говорю, создаем в `Canvas` пустой объект и в него помещаем все ваши элементы. В принципи можно их все перетащить в `Panel` и включать, выключать видимость непосредственно объекта `Panel`